# Polymer: How to render refreshed custom components on Safari (Polyfill)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, polymer

I am dealing with a web app using polymer custom components. 
In order to be rendered on Safari 7.0 I am relying on the platform.js script and it works. 
The problem is that when I refresh custom components by means of an ajax call and innerHTML replace of a div the refreshed components are not rendered (because the platform.js script has been already executed for that page).

How am I supposed to manage such situation?

Comment: This should work as expected. Can you post code of what you're doing and how you're "refreshing" the elements?

Comment: I am basically making a $.post to a HTTPHandler (Google App Engine with webapp2)making a delete on the datastore. in the post 'done' handler I am making a $.get to another HattpHandler returning the html (Jinja2 template) with the updated dataset (which works fine). The returned html is finally used in the done method to update a div of the page with this script document.querySelector('#container_div').innerHTML= variableWithTheHtml